# Unable to run the output for ECL in VSCODE. (HPCC Workunit)

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I'm using HPCC workunit.
Every time  I submit, the result is always empty (...empty...). I have tried creating new file and then working on it but nothing works.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvNUy.jpg)
(image)
What should I do ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you've provided, it looks like you are just compiling your code:

[image]

If you want your code to be executed on the cluster so you can see its output, then you need to click on the "submit" button on your VSCode instead of the "compile" button. Please see below. Also, you can submit your code by hitting F5 in your keyboard.

[image]

Lastly, a Workunit (WU) that has been successfully submitted and executed will be displayed with a "checkmark" symbol on your WU list panel, see below:

[image]